# Inline кнопка 'Удалить'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telegram

хочу спросить как можно сделать Inline кнопку удалить?

Хочу сделать как тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии Inline кнопки "Удалить" сообщение удаляется.

**Inline Mode** в **BotFather** включил.

Код:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['slap', 'ударить', 'удар'])
async def send_slap(message: types.Message):
    hugtarget = message.get_args().split()
    your_id = message.from_user.id
    your_name = message.from_user.username
    hugimg = nekos.img('slap')
    if not hugtarget or hugtarget[0][0] != '@':
      await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Введите /slap @имя_пользователя')
    else:
      extension = os.path.splitext(hugimg)[1]
      if extension == '.jpg':
        await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, hugimg, caption=f'[{hugtarget[0]}], вас ударил [{your_name}](tg://user?id={str(your_id)})', parse_mode="Markdown")
      elif extension == '.png':
        await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, hugimg, caption=f'[{hugtarget[0]}], вас ударил [{your_name}](tg://user?id={str(your_id)})', parse_mode="Markdown")
      elif extension == '.gif':
        await bot.send_animation(message.chat.id, hugimg, caption=f'[{hugtarget[0]}], вас ударил [{your_name}](tg://user?id={str(your_id)})', parse_mode="Markdown")
      else:
        await message.answer('Нет картинки')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это проще чем кажется. Вам никакой Inline Mode не нужен если вы не используете этот самый Inline Mode. (это не Inline кнопки)

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="status", callback_data="delet_cur_message"))
    await message.answer("text", reply_markup=markup)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="delet_cur_message")
async def ca(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer()
    await call.message.delete()
```